# TortoiseSVN is showing the Question mark decorators

Tags: svn, debugging, tortoisesvn

At the root of my d: drive, TortoiseSVN is showing the question mark decorators on all the folders. The d: drive is not a SVN working copy. How do I remove the decorators?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TSVNCache, which TortoiseSVN uses to keep those icons uptodate, doesn't always make the correct choices about which directories need decoration.  You can limit which directories it will consider by:

- In **TortoiseSVN|Settings|Look and
  Feel|Icon Overlays**
- In the **Drive
  Types** section

  - Mark the drive types you want
    monitored.
  - Use *Include paths* for the
    directories you want monitored
  - Use *exclude paths* for directories to be excluded (strangely enough)

I have only **Fixed Drives** checked.

Exclude paths:

```
c:\*
```

Include paths:

```
c:\cygwin\home\me\workspaces\*
c:\dev\*
d:\development\*
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two things you should check.

1. Remove any .svn folders from the root level of your drive.

The .svn folder is hidden so you will have to make sure Windows Explorer shows hidden files and folders.

Open a command prompt and run the following command.

> > tortoiseproc /command:rebuildiconcache
> >     
> >     If this doesn't remove the icon overlays, you may need to reboot as well.

Comment: After I accidentally checked out a single file from a SVN repo right on my desktop, all its icons got decorated. Thanks a lot, removing the hidden folder did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The question mark decorators can be deactivated as shown here.

Go to Tortoise SVN >> Settings >> Icon Overlays

In the Drive Types section

Un-check

- Fixed drivers

And check

- Show excluded root folders as normal

Answer (score 0):

If a restart doesn't solve it (i.e. it's not a TortoiseSVN bug), the root folder is probably a working copy created by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the svn sync we have to 'un-version' the folder/drive, the proper way to do it is as follows

Click on the folder/drive --> selectTortoiseSVN --> Export --> choose the same location as the folder currently is in, export the folder to itself